# Can I refer to the object of the previous list item with "it"?

Tags: pronouns, semantics, lists

Is it ambiguous to use *it* to refer to the dog in the following sentence?

> I was seen driving the car, hitting the dog, and burying *it*.

Comment: You're obviously asking if, given the way your sentence is framed, "What is being buried: the car or the dog?" You could make the sentence clearer, I think, by simply adding the word "then" after the word "and." @ChaslyfromUK and his idea of using semicolons is also a good idea. Another option: "I was seen doing two things: driving the car that hit the dog, and then burying it" (and that option is but one of many). Don

Comment: Note that *nobody* reading that sentence would think you buried the car.

Answer (score 0):

> I was seen driving the car, hitting the dog and burying it.

I would say that the problem here is that the two commas initially give the impression that they are a pair, thus making 'hitting the dog' parenthetical. Commas aren't strong enough (in my opinion) to indicate a list in this situation.

I suggest using semicolons.

I was seen driving the car; hitting the dog; and burying it.

> The semi-colon represents a break within a sentence
>   that is stronger than a comma, but less final than a full stop. It
>   enables the writer to avoid over use of the comma and preserves the
>   finality of the full stop. Semi-colons are used to separate items in a
>   list and to link closely related sentences.
>
> [University of Leicester](http://www2.le.ac.uk/offices/ld/resources/writing/grammar/grammar-guides/semicolon)

**Update: 17 Sep 2015**

I forgot to answer the main question. My answer is no, it is not ambiguous. The word 'it' refers to the nearest noun, i.e. the dog.

Comment: The OP's sentence has a second comma - just before the word 'and'. This allows *hitting the dog* to be a parenthetical phrase, in turn allowing *it* to refer to the car.